# window.location.hash without refreshing

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash

I am using a jQuery script to dynamically load in content to a div. When I click on a link, the new content fades in and the url changes to index.html#first-item, index.html#second-item etc.

Now, I want to be able to affect an element based on the URL hash. I have the following piece of code which works fine except but only works when I refresh the page, not when the new content fades in.

```
   if (window.location.hash == "#first-item") {
        $("#main-nav").addClass("test");
    }
```

Ajax jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.more').on('click', function() {
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "250");
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'100%' }).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'100%' },function() {
            $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html ' + href, function() {
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

slide-fade-content.html markup looks like this

```
<div id="section-one">
content
</div>

<div id="section-two">
content
</div>


<div id="section-three">
content
</div>
```

And the main page markup looks like this

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li><a class="more" href="#first-item">First Item</a></li>
<li><a class="more" href="#second-item">Second Item</a></li>
<li><a class="more" href="#third-item">Third Item</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the if condition in the document ready function and additionally use a callback in the respective load function

Comment: Sorry but I am new to jquery, what exactly do I callback?

Comment: post the whole jquery code that is relevant please

Comment: No problem, added the Ajax code + markup